# How to keep more than one tables in room database

Tags: android, android-room

If we are implementing **Room** Library for local database in our app and we have more than one tables then how many room database are required

Answer (score 0):

Room is an SQL database, relational, not a document-based NoSQL database.

So the answer to the body of your question is: 1 database

The answer to the title of your question is: Create additional tables just as you did the first one

Room Structure docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/